# Symbolic derivatives throwing error in older versions of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, backwards-compatibility

I have this MATLAB code that uses symbolic functions for certain operations and the `sym/diff` function throws a very annoying error when I run it in the 2015b version in my server. My laptop with 2018a runs the same code with no problems. The error in particular is:

```
Error using sym/diff (line 68)
Error using class
The first argument to function CLASS must be a struct.
```

An MWE of the part of the code that's throwing the error is the following:

```
Thrust_fcn = @(r) 5 * exp(-2*r)
syms r;
diff_fcn = diff(Thrust_fcn, r);
```

This is the code in the built-in sym/diff function that's throwing the error:

```
try
    if nargin == 1
        r = class(maplemex(0,'MTM:-diff',m),'sym');
    elseif nargin == 2
        r = class(maplemex(0,'MTM:-diff',m,n),'sym');
    else
        r = class(maplemex(0,'MTM:-diff',m,n,u),'sym');
    end
catch
    error(lasterr);
end
```

I've checked the code of the `sym/diff` function on 2018a and is completely different, it is a ~300 lines piece of code.

Any ideas on how to get this to work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Install 2015 in your laptop and wrote code for the same version....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Symbolic Function

When you use `@(r)`, you're generating a `function_handle`, which is not part of the Symbolic toolbox:

```
>> Thrust_fcn = @(r) 5 * exp(-2*r);
>> whos Thrust_fcn
  Name            Size            Bytes  Class              Attributes
  Thrust_fcn      1x1                32  function_handle
```

Instead, try creating `r` first, and making `Thrust_fcn` using the sym `r`

```
>> syms r;
>> Thrust_fcn = 5 * exp(-2*r); %%% Not using @(r)! %%%

>> whos Thrust_fcn
  Name            Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
  Thrust_fcn      1x1                 8  sym
```

Now that Thrust_fcn is a sym, try calling `diff(Thrust_fcn, r)`

### Calling MuPAD's Function (Within MATLAB)

If you'd like to continue using a function handle, you can use MuPAD's functionality while remaining within the MATLAB editor.
[This MathWorks Documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html) explains a few ways to use MuPAD's functions, but I'll provide a working example:

```
% Notice that 'syms r' is never called.
% You may want to ensure your previous variable 'r' has been cleared first.
clear r;

Thrust_fcn = @(r) 5 * exp(-2*r);
feval(symengine,'diff',Thrust_fcn,'r')
```

This acts the same way as if you were to define a function in MuPAD, and call `diff` on `Thrust_fcn` with the input `'r'`.